# Importing/using Java classes in Grails

Tags: java, grails

I have an existing RESTful service created with Jersey, for which I created 2 clients (also Java), one using the Jersey client API, and one using Apache HTTP client.

I don't have much frontend experience- I've used Spring/Java a little bit and understand the basic concepts, but I thought I would try learning Grails.  I wanted to just use Grails for the front-end (So, no reliance on GORM), and use my existing service for business logic/interaction with storage).  Would it be possible for me to just include the jar w/ my existing client and use it in my Grails controller, or will I need to write a new Groovy client for it using a Groovy (or an already included java library)?

I'd also be happy to get opinions on if this seems like a good idea, or if it seems pointless to use Grails if I'm not taking advantage of GORM/Grails data persistence functionality?  I figured I could still get the advantage of 'convention over configuration', and maybe some other advantages of the framework, but again I'm pretty new to web development so I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: just found https://grails.org/plugin/jaxrs which could be a possible solution.  Not yet sure if I include that library if I could just import my existing java client, or would still have to write a new groovy client using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your existing java client in grails. If your existing client jar is in a maven repo then you can specify dependency for the jar in BuildConfig.groory. or else you can just drop the jar inside your grails projects lib directory.

Also, if your client code depends on any third party jars, you will have to specify dependency for that third party jars in BuildConfig.groovy - See grails docs for how to specify dependencies.

If you want, you can use grails [rest-client-builder](https://grails.org/plugin/rest-client-builder) plugin to write your client too.

Comment: Thanks sudhir.   I did end up coming across rest-client-builder, and decided I might as well try to write a groovy client using that just for the sake of learning anyway.  So far that has worked.

Thanks for your other solution as well- using the direct jar copying method I knew could result in pain trying to get all the downstream dependencies and dealing with potential dependency conflicts etc... my client isn't in a maven repository, it's in bitbucket right now, but I think there are ways to front bitbucket and other git repositories as remote maven repositories from in initial read up